# Detect edit on a cell using VLOOKUP - Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a document with 2 sheets.
I use Vlookup on my first sheet on a column (Q) to get data from the second sheet.

Everything's working as expected.

My Google Sheet is used with Zapier to update data in a Shopify store. If a cell is modify on my first sheet on selected columns (N or Q) , a modification date is added in the column O of my file, firing Zapier tasks.

Everything work's fine if the data is modified in the N column.

**But it doesn't work in the column Q containing the VLOOKUP formula in it.** If I manually add something in Q (not a formula) it's working, but everything coming from the VLOOKUP formula isn't considerated as an edit.

I'm using the following app scripts to scan for edits.

How can my script detect VLOOKUP changes as an edit ?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Your sheet params
  var sheetName = "Inventaire";
  var dateModifiedColumnLetter = 'O';


  var range = e.range; // range just edited
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetName) {
 

    // If the column isn't our modified date column
    if (range.getColumn() == 14 || range.getColumn() == 17 ) { 
      var row = range.getRow();
      var time = new Date();
      time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-04:00", "MM/dd/yy, HH:mm:ss");
      var dateModifiedRange = sheet.getRange(dateModifiedColumnLetter + row.toString());
      dateModifiedRange.setValue(time);
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I confirm my understanding for your question? In your situation, when the Spreadsheet is updated by Zapier, the column "N" is updated and the values of the column "Q" are changed by the VLOOKUP formula. Is my understanding correct? If I misunderstood your situation, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike in fact Zapier updates my Shopify store if column "N" or "Q" is changed. So my Google Sheet is the one that's triggering my Zapier.

I understand from Cooper that onEdit() trigger is only created on user edits. So Q was edited by a formula and is then ignored by onEdit().

So now i'm trying to update, via my app script, my first sheet data on the edit of the second sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that in your situation, when the Spreadsheet is manually updated, Zapier is called. I had thought that when the Spreadsheet is updated by Zapier, the column "N" of Spreadsheet is updated. I could notice that I had misunderstood your situation. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2):

onEdit() trigger is only created on user edits. No work around.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't realize it was only triggering by human action.

So I suppose I must detect the human change on my second sheet, then update my first sheet.

I'm not sure how to update another sheet via apps script. I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121561/google-app-script-update-cell-value-in-another-sheet but i'm not sure how to switch between sheets.